# unusual AJAX behavior

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's my HTML

```
<form id="the_form">
          Zip / Postal Code: <input id="zip" type="text" name="zip"><br/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton">
</form>


<div id="output"></div>
```

Here's my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function() {

   $("#submitButton").on("click",function(){

     var value_to_send_to_php = $.trim($("#zip").val());

        if(value_to_send_to_php != "") {

              $.post("formphptoajax_rb.php",  $("#the_form").serializeArray() , function(data) {
                  //#1 doesn't work here
              });   
                  //#2 doesn't work here         
        }    
                  //#3 doesn't work here
    });

      $("#output").text("success");

  });
</script>
```

The above jQuery works fine. That is, on clicking `submit`, I get "success" output in the `div` with id "output".

What I can't understand is why I don't get the same result when I place `$("#output").text("success");` at the locations marked #1, #2, or #3.

At #1 and #2 I get no output. At #3, I get "success" for a fraction of a second and then it vanishes.

Comment: Because you don't stop the default behaviour of the `submit` button. The form is submitted after your `click` handler has been executed which is, in this case, the same as a page-reload.

Comment: Start looking at #3, because if #3 doesn't happen, the rest wont either. The only possible ways for #3 to not happen would be if an error is occuring before it, or, your event handler never gets called, which shouldn't be possible given your code. comment out the form tags and try again, watching your console. **My guess is #3 IS happening, you just aren't seeing it.**

Comment: You have to "return false;" at the end of the clicked function to prevent postback. And your call "$("#output").text("success");" at the scope you have it does not make any sense. It will be invoked always regardless on  success or error of ajax call.

Comment: @Kevin B - #3 is probably never happening, because of page postback. The page is refreshed immediately after ajax call is made, so there is no time to ajax can return anything. Success nor error.

Comment: @paYa no, it should still happen, because the ajax call is asynchronous. Code will continue all the way to the end, just in case a return false or e.preventDefault is present. the browser cannot begin to postback until after that function returns.

Comment: @Kevin - I know what you mean. You're right, but it does not matter, because the original context does not exists at the time of ajax complete.

Comment: @paYa #3 is not part of the `$.post()` call.

Comment: Andreas - Of course it is not.

Comment: Anyway, to make it work correctly, the "$("#output").text("success");" have to be at '#1' place and "return false;" at the end of click handler.

Comment: @KevinB yes, #3 is indeed happening. I mentioned in my post that it displays and then vanishes.

Comment: @Andreas if it's the same as a page reload, why does the current code produce output that sticks. Why doesn't that get erased on reload?

Comment: @paYa could you please point me to a reference on what "page postback" means in this context? Appreciate the help. Also, I didn't quite understand the phrase "the original context does not exists at the time of ajax complete". Thanks.

Comment: You mean the "success" message? This text is written in the DomReady event handler which is independent from your `click` handler with the ajax request.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you. Do you know what paYa means by "page postback"?

Comment: @Andreas - Yes, in the original code snippet the "success" message is shown when the DOM is ready. But from my point of view it makes no sense. I suppose, that the questioner wants to show the "success" message when his AJAX async callback is successfull. When he wants the "success" message on DOM ready, then it is ok just as it is now.

Comment: @user1883050 - please, see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as the click handler, the page is also submitting since you have clicked a "submit" button.

Use input type="button" instead. This is what it is designed for: a non-submitting button.

Comment: Well technically since it's a form, a submit button is correct. You just need to prevent the default action of the button when handling it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do e.preventDefault() or return false from your handler. Also, what you have there will show success on load, not after clicking the button.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's get straight.
I suppose, that the $.post calls AJAX async callback (**this is important, because if you don't want ASYNC callback then I poorly understood your question and my conclusions are wrong**).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("document").ready(function() {

    $("#submitButton").on("click",function(){

      var value_to_send_to_php = $.trim($("#zip").val());

      if(value_to_send_to_php != "") {

        // - ok, we have "#zip" value filled, so let's take "#the_form" data and sends them asynchronously to server

        $.post("formphptoajax_rb.php",  $("#the_form").serializeArray() , function(data) {
          //#1 doesn't work here

          // - great, our AJAX callback was successful, so we can inform user, that save or whatever operation was successfull
          // - now we can process "data" returned from server
          // - and we can show the success message - $("#output").text("success");

          // BUT, all this will happen only, when you prevent page from full postback (which refresh the whole page)
        });   

        //#2 doesn't work here         


      }

      //#3 doesn't work here

      // - in this place you have to prevent page from continue submitting (therefore full page postback is initiated)
      // - so there should be "return false;" (without quotes of course)
      // - or you can use "e.preventDefault();" here (as someone already mentioned), but in that case you have to change your click event handler signature from "function()" to "function(e)"
    });

    $("#output").text("success");

  });

</script>
```

Simplified, [postback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback) is called when submit button is clicked - browser takes the form data and refresh the page (while form data is send to server as request params). It is synchronous HTTP POST request. Well, the term "PostBack" is used mainly in ASP or ASP.NET.

As of "the original context does not exists at the time of ajax complete" - I mean, that when you send async callback to server, but immediately after that the page is refreshed (because of postback), then the original
initiator of async callback no longer exists and there is no routine which can process the result of that callback (success nor failed).

Comment: Thank you for your considered and helpful answer. Here, does "postback" happen mainly because the input type was "submit"? It wouldn't happen if it was a "button" input type or simply a "button" element, correct?

Comment: @user1883050 - that's correct. Input type button nor button element does not initiate postback.

Comment: Gotcha! It was the darn "submit" type button that was causing all this confusion for me.